# Generic name for the active log file

Tags: java, spring, logging, slf4j

I have the following `logback.xml` file for my spring boot application where I intend to create daily log files:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration scan="true">
    <appender name="rollingFile" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- daily rollover -->
            <fileNamePattern>./logs/my-log-file.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
            <maxHistory>15</maxHistory>
            <totalSizeCap>15MB</totalSizeCap>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
            <Pattern>%d [%-5thread] [%-1p] [%logger{35}] - %msg%n</Pattern>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <root level="WARN">
        <appender-ref ref="rollingFile"/>
    </root>
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="rollingFile"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

The files are created like this:

```
my-log-file.2018-11-10.log
my-log-file.2018-11-11.log
my-log-file.2018-11-12.log
```

I am looking to have the current active log file without the date so it is generic name like `my-log-file.log` and only when the date rolls to a new day, the file is renamed with date.

What change is required on the `logback.xml` to enable this configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `<file>` to the `<appender>`, like so:

```
<appender name="rollingFile" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>./logs/my-log-file.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <!-- daily rollover -->
        <fileNamePattern>./logs/my-log-file.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
        <maxHistory>15</maxHistory>
        <totalSizeCap>15MB</totalSizeCap>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
        <Pattern>%d [%-5thread] [%-1p] [%logger{35}] - %msg%n</Pattern>
    </layout>
</appender>
```

From the [Logback documentation](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#tbrpFileNamePattern):

> Note that the `file` property in `RollingFileAppender` (the parent of
>   `TimeBasedRollingPolicy`) can be either set or omitted. By setting the
>   `file` property of the containing `FileAppender`, you can decouple the
>   location of the active log file and the location of the archived log
>   files. The current logs will be always targeted at the file specified
>   by the `file` property. It follows that the name of the currently active
>   log file will not change over time. However, if you choose to omit the
>   `file` property, then the active file will be computed anew for each
>   period based on the value of `fileNamePattern`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer